# How do I filter only letters in jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

For example I have these strings, how would I filter to only get letters:

"0asd0"
"2aqw"
"3qwe"

How would I get it to be asd, aqw and qwe?

Comment: Within the jinja template or just in python?

Comment: Jinja2 template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert string to list, filter out (*reject*) digits and the *join* list back into string. For instance:

```
{% for str in test %}
    {{ str | list | reject("in", ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]) | join }}
{% endfor %}
```

If **test** here is a list of strings, each item of this list will be cleared from digits.